# Dash Lights Sequence

Tags: tucson

Hyundai Tucson 2006

When I start the car, the Brake! & Battery lights stay on for about 4 minutes.

They then go out and the seatbelt light flashes for 1 minute.

Then everything is out.

Same sequence each time I've started it (Last 5 times).

Is this a designated sequence, or is something really wrong??

Comment: Has it always done this or just the last few times you have started it?

Comment: It just started to do this yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

When you first start a car it's common for all the dashboard lights to come on for a few seconds, but then disappear unless there's some sort of problem. The Brake light would indicate your emergency brake is on or that there's a fault in your braking system somewhere, and the battery light would indicate an alternator problem or low battery charge. The lights shouldn't go out unless the problem is resolved, so this is strange behavior.

What you need to do is get the codes read from the OBD port using a special reader. Any decent mechanic should be able to do this, or if you have the skills you can rent one and do it yourself. Either way the codes will tell you whether there's a problem with those systems or some sort of instrumentation issue.

Comment: Not sure where the questioner is located, but in the USA you can get the codes read for free at any Advance Auto Parts or AutoZone store.

Comment: That's handy @MosheKatz

Comment: autozone and the like read eobd2 codes? i doubt that they use anything other than a basic scanner.

Comment: Basic isn't bad if it can do the job @Ben

Comment: what i mean is they do global obd2 at best and likely wouldn’t cover abs or srs.

Comment: No experience with Autozone here @Ben.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm going to go get the OBD reading.  Oddly enough, it is now fine IF the car has sat for a few hours. But if I stop and restart it the lights do the above sequence...